# How to match single html tag with special src?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

my regexp online address: https://regex101.com/r/JSPy5Z/1

I want to replace `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/abcd.css" />` using `abcd.css` content with an empty string.

input: `<link ref="stylesheet" href="/dist/qwefqwefqwef.css" /><link ref="stylesheet" href="/dist/abcd.css" />`

output: `<link ref="stylesheet" href="/dist/qwefqwefqwef.css" />`

[image]

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding the question. Are you trying to capture the filename within the `src` attribute in a link element? So only the filename of the path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Do you want to capture all the `link` tags with `abcd.css`?

Comment: replace all link tags with `abcd.css`

Comment: You can use the regular expression as follows /<link[ ]+rel=\"[a-z]+\"[ ]+href=\"[a-z0-9\/.]+\"[ ]+\/>/gm

Comment: @Raju not right using the regexp

Comment: @TheNewGuy I want to replace the `<link />` tag with `href="/dist/abcd.css"` attr

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't belive this can be accomplished with just regex. You can certainly use regex to match/capture. You would most likely need a programming language for that, and given that you've tagged this question with `javascript`, the method you're looking for is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex to match, then replace it with an empty string:

`<link[^>]*href="\S*abcd\.css"[\s\S]*\/>`

Two major changes:

1. Your `[^>]` was misplaced. Now it captures only a single `link` tag.
2. The capturing group is not required in this case, so I removed it.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JSPy5Z/3)

Comment: `/<link[^>]*href="\S**abcd\.css"[^>]*>/gi` is better.

Comment: @K.King What is `**` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `ref`s in your links to `rel`s, which is the correct attribute name. If I understand what you're trying to do, this should work for you.

```js
const
  links = `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/qwefqwefqwef.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/abcd.css" />`,
  content = `abcd`, // set this to whatever you want to filter out
  re = RegExp(String.raw`<link rel="[^"]*" href="[^"]*?${content}\.css" />`);

console.log(`regular expression: ${re}`);
console.log(`output: ${links.replace(re, ``)}`);
```